# Split Comma separated Strings & divide value of second column into separated Rows using Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to split a column that contains Strings separated by commas into rows (easy part) but also divide the second column by the number of item in the comma separated string.

Input -

```
+--------------------+----+  
|11710, 11830        | 10 |  
+--------------------+----+  
|11711, 11015, 10020 |  9 |  
+--------------------+----+
```

Expected result

```
+------+---+  
|11710 | 5 |  
+------+---+  
|11830 | 5 |  
+------+---+  
|11711 | 3 |  
+------+---+  
|11015 | 3 |    
+------+---+  
|10020 | 3 |  
+------+---+
```

Query:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '11710, 11830' id, 10 hours UNION ALL
  SELECT '11711, 11015, 10020', 9
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(uniq_id) REPLACE(uniq_id AS id)
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(id)) uniq_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```sql
WITH data_ AS (
  SELECT [11710, 11830] id, 10 hours UNION ALL
  SELECT [11711, 11015, 10020], 9
)
select  itm,
        cast((hours/array_length(id)) as int64) as div ,
        hours from data_,unnest(id) as itm
```

Comment: `WITH data_ AS (
  SELECT [11710, 11830] id, 10 hours UNION ALL
  SELECT [11711, 11015, 10020], 9
)
select  itm,
        cast((hours/array_length(split(id))) as int64) as div ,
        hours from data_,unnest(id) as itm `

Answer (score 0):

Base on your sharing script, might also consider below approach.

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '11710, 11830' id, 10 hours UNION ALL
  SELECT '11711, 11015, 10020', 9
)


SELECT 
    TRIM(VALUE) AS id,
    CAST(HOURS/ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(id,',')) AS INT64) AS HOURS
FROM `project.dataset.table`,UNNEST(split(id,',')) AS VALUE
```